# Docker run ENTRYPOINT does not replace environment variable

Tags: docker

I have an entry point as shown here

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/java ... /usr/path/$FILE
```

I am trying to pass an environment variable while starting container

```
-e FILE=myfile.txt
```

However this value does not seem to be replaced. Java throws an exception that `/usr/path is a directory` . If I hard code the entrypoint with a file name in the dockerfile, it works perfectly fine.

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/java ... /usr/path/myfile.txt
```

It confirms $FILE is not replaced.

How to fix this?

NOTE:

Interestingly docker-compose works perfectly fine!!

```
environment:
  - FILE=myfile.txt
```

Comment: try run -e "FILE=myfile.txt"

Comment: Thanks. It does not help. it still throws the same error

Comment: What if you try this form? ENTRYPOINT ["..."] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to ensure that the [shell form of `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), that you correctly are using, does substitute the environment variable `$FILE`, add an `exec`:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec /usr/bin/java ... "/usr/path/$FILE"
```

Then check that your `docker run -e FILE=xxx yourImage` does work.

That supposes that your Dockefile includes an [`ENV FILE aDefaultFile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive, in order for `docker run -e` to work.

Comment: @KitKarson Did you add the double-quotes: does a `docker history` on your build image shows `$FILE` in the last layer?

Comment: I did this `ENTRYPOINT exec /usr/bin/java ... "/usr/path/$FILE"`  the history shows `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh" "-c" "exec /usr/bin/java ... \"/usr/path/$FILE\""]`

Comment: @KitKarson That looks good. Does a `docker run -e FILE=xxx` replace `$FILE` for the running container?

Comment: nope. it does not replace for sure. well.. it replaces with an empty value

Comment: @KitKarson Does your Dockerfile declares `ENV FILE`?

Comment: @KitKarson I have edited the answer to make the ENV step clearer.